# How to make Jupyter Notebook to point to the same Python installation as Terminal on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am on a Ubuntu machine. I installed Jupyter Notebook using the following command.

> sudo snap install jupyter

But Jupyter cannot find any of the installed python packages which were installed using terminal. I checked if jupyter and terminal are pointing to same python installation using this code.

> import sys; print(sys.executable)

Terminal shows this output.

> '/usr/bin/python3'

And Jupyter shows this one.

> '/snap/jupyter/6/bin/python'

Now I want the jupyter to point the same installation path as the terminal shows. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your jupyter is not placed in default packages location due to installing it with snap. install jupyter with pip this way: `pip install jupyter`
if you dont have pip then download it. it usually is included in python package